# How to show that $\lim_n \beta_n|f(\alpha_n x)|=0 \, \, a.e.$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, $\{\beta_n\}$ a positive sequence and $\{\alpha_n\}$ such that $\sum_n \beta_n/|\alpha_n|<\infty. $ Prove that
> $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \beta_n|f(\alpha_n x)|=0    \, \, a.e.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: This follows from the *a priori* stronger fact that $$\int\sum_n \beta_n|f(\alpha_n x)|<\infty.$$